# Please help me with this problem: $(1+i)^{3+4i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $(1+i)^{3+4i}$.  Can someone help me understand this problem?  I broke it up first,

$$(1+i)^3  (1+i)^{4i} = (-2+2i)(-4)^i$$

Is this the correct way to go about solving this?
Thank you!

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: @ kjetil Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the principal determination of the $\log$ function:

$$\log z=\log|z|+i\arg z,\quad -\pi<\arg z\le \pi$$
we have
$$(1+i)^{3+4i}=\exp((3+4i)\log(1+i))=\exp((3+4i)(\log(\sqrt2)+i\frac\pi4))$$
Can you take it from here using that
$$\exp(a+ib)=e^a(\cos b+i\sin b)\qquad?$$

Comment: I'm still confused.  Would that be e^3(cos4+isin4)?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Needs an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)^{3+4i}=e^{(3+4i)\text{Log}(1+i)}$$

Now using [Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) formula, $\displaystyle 1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\frac\pi4}$

$\displaystyle\implies\text{Log}(1+i)=\log\sqrt2+\text{Log}(e^{i\frac\pi4})$

$\displaystyle=\frac12\log2+\left(2n\pi+\frac\pi4\right)i$ where $n$ is any integer

Finally express as $e^{A+iB}=e^A\cdot e^{iB}$ where $A,B$ are real and apply Euler formula